# invalid literal for int() with base 10, tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, integer

```
from numpy import char
import tweepy


consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

FILE_NAME = 'cached.txt'
>where I get the problem, I tried using char and float but failed
def read_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id

def store_seen(FILE_NAME, last_seen_id):
    file_write = open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
    file_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    file_write.close()
    return

mentions = api.mentions_timeline()

for mention in reversed(mentions):
    if '@XXXXXX' in mention.text.lower(read_seen(FILE_NAME)):
        print(str(mention.id) + ' - ' + mention.text)
        api.update_status("@" + mention.user.scree_name + " Auto reply work", mention.id)
        store_seen(FILE_NAME, mention.id)"
```

```
File "c:\Users\91951\Desktop\twitterbot\tweepy3.py", line 32, in <module>
    if '@XXXXXX' in mention.text.lower(read_seen(FILE_NAME)):
  File "c:\Users\91951\Desktop\twitterbot\tweepy3.py", line 19, in read_seen
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

This is a code for a bot, the yutoube tutorial exactly shows to type int, so I did, the presenter doesn't face any problems, but I do, this program **replies to mentioned tweets, saves tweet id
to not repeat again**

Comment: It is trying to convert an empty string `''` to an int, which isn't possible. Try to check the contents of the file to ensure that that is correct.

Comment: there's nothing, apparently, in the `'cached.txt'` file. maybe verify what should be in there, put it there, and retry.

Comment: When you first create the file, you need to put a number in it. Or you can use `try/except` to handle the error and use a default value.